# rails, voting on nested comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails. Getting various errors while trying to add a voting feature via the acts_as_votable  gem on nested comments.

The acts_as_votable works with the posts, but not with the nested comments under the posts.

With :

```html
<%= link_to "Like", like_post_comment_path(@post, @comment), method: :put do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true">Yes</i>
                    <%= @p.get_upvotes.size %>
          <% end %>
```

I get the error:
No route matches {:action=>"upvote", :controller=>"comments", :id=>nil, :post_id=>"1"}, missing required keys: [:id]

With:

```html
<%= link_to "Like", like_post_comment_path(@post, @comment.id), method: :put do %>
                    <i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true">Yes</i>
                    <%= @p.get_upvotes.size %>
          <% end %>
```

I get the error:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

I have tried various combinations  as the parameters. All produce an error.

My Comments controller:

```html
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: [:upvote, :downvote, :create, :destroy, :edit, :update]
    before_action :find_comment, only: [:upvote, :downvote :destroy, :update, :edit, :comment_owner ]
    before_action :comment_owner, only: [:destroy, :edit, :update]
     
    def new
        @comment = Comment.new
        @post = Post.new
    end

      def create
        @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:content))
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id
        @comment.save
        
        if @comment.save
            redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
       @comment.destroy
       redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end

    def edit
        @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
        @p = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end

    def update
      if @comment.update(params[:comment].permit(:content))
        respond_to do |f|
            if (@comment.save) 
                f.html { redirect_to "/explore", notice: "Comment edited!" }
            elsif
                f.html { redirect_to "/explore", notice: "Error: Your Comment is the same!." }
           else
               render 'edit'
        #f.html { render 'edit'} ## Specify the format in which you are rendering "new" page      
            end
         end
        end
    end
   
    def upvote    
        @comment.upvote_from current_user
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end

    def downvote
        @comment.downvote_from current_user
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    end

    private

    def find_post
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    end

    def find_comment
        @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])      
    end

    def comment_owner
        unless current_user.id == @comment.user_id
            flash[:notice] = "You can't do that!"
            redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
        end
    end
    

end
```

Comment model:

```html
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true

  belongs_to :user
  acts_as_votable
  
 # scope :desc
default_scope { order(created_at: :desc) }

end
```

Post model:

```html
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
  attr_accessor :post_id
  acts_as_votable
  
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100} # Questions are capped at 100 chars.
  default_scope { order(cached_votes_score: :DESC) }
  
end

User model:

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :posts
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable

acts_as_voter

 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         
         has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
def user
          user = User.find_by(params[:id]) 
         end
```

Routes:

like_post_comment PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/like(.:format)    comments#upvote

dislike_post_comment PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/dislike(.:format) comments#downvote

Comment: look into pry or byebug. I am sure you can find more info

Comment: or google this undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass